# adding triangle in caption to point to figure (tufte class)

Tags: captions, tufte

I'm using the Tufte class for a document with lots of figures, and some of my readers have complained that it is not always easy to locate the caption of figures that are not in the margin.  So I'd like to define (and then use) variants the `\caption` macro display a small triangle in front of the caption, pointing to the figure.   For instance `\captiondown{my caption}` would display "▼ **Figure** 3: my caption".

It's not clear to me how to write such macros.  I thought I could achieve that by redefining `\figurename`, but looking at the example below it works in the `marginfigure` environment, not in the `figure` and `figure*` environments.  Can someone help?

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,nobib]{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{showframe}

\renewcommand{\figurename}{\textbf{Figure}}

\begin{document}
\begin{marginfigure}
  \tikz\fill[cyan] rectangle(\marginparwidth,2);
  \renewcommand{\figurename}{$\blacktriangle$~\textbf{Figure}}
  \caption{Some caption for the blue figure.}
\end{marginfigure}
\begin{figure}
  \tikz\fill[yellow]rectangle(\textwidth,4);
  \renewcommand{\figurename}{$\blacktriangleleft$~\textbf{Figure}} %ignored?
  \caption[][3cm]{Some caption for the yellow figure.}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure*}
  \tikz\fill[magenta]rectangle(\textwidth,3);
  \renewcommand{\figurename}{$\blacktriangledown$~\textbf{Figure}} %ignored?
  \caption[][-4.5cm]{Some caption for the magenta figure.}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

**Update:**

Here is a variant where I redefine `\fnum@figure` instead.  I get the desired output if I redefine that macro before the `figure` and `figure*` environment, so I guess I'll make do with that.

I'd still very much prefer to be able to call `\captiondown{my caption}` inside those environments, but I do not know how to do that.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,nobib]{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{showframe}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\captionsbelow}{%
  \renewcommand{\fnum@figure}{$\blacktriangle$~\textbf{\figurename}~\thefigure}}
\newcommand{\captionsright}{%
  \renewcommand{\fnum@figure}{$\blacktriangleleft$~\textbf{\figurename}~\thefigure}}
\newcommand{\captionsabove}{%
  \renewcommand{\fnum@figure}{$\blacktriangledown$~\textbf{\figurename}~\thefigure}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\captionsbelow
\begin{marginfigure}
  \tikz\fill[cyan] rectangle(\marginparwidth,2);
  \caption{Some caption for the blue figure.}
\end{marginfigure}
\captionsright
\begin{figure}
  \tikz\fill[yellow]rectangle(\textwidth,4);
  \caption[][3cm]{Some caption for the yellow figure.}
\end{figure}
\captionsabove
\begin{figure*}
  \tikz\fill[magenta]rectangle(\textwidth,3);
  \caption[][-4.5cm]{Some caption for the magenta figure.}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

**Final update**:

Using all the input I got, a managed to patch the Tufte definitions in a way that the orientation is redefined in each float according to the location of the figure.  (I'm just not bothering with recto-verso mode, which I don't use, but extending that to support it should not be a problem.)

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,nobib]{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\fnum@figure}{\captiontriangle~\textbf{\figurename}~\thefigure}
\newcommand{\captionbelow}{\gdef\captiontriangle{$\blacktriangle$}}
\newcommand{\captionright}{\gdef\captiontriangle{$\blacktriangleleft$}}
\newcommand{\captionabove}{\gdef\captiontriangle{$\blacktriangledown$}}
% Use \captionbelow by default, for margin figures
\AtBeginDocument{\captionbelow}
\AfterEndEnvironment{@tufte@float}{\captionbelow}
% automatically change the triangle for other captions
\AtEndEnvironment{@tufte@float}{%
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{@tufte@float@star}}%
    {\ifthenelse{\equal{\floatalignment}{b}}{\captionabove}{\captionbelow}}%
    {\captionright}}
\makeatother

\setcounter{totalnumber}{4}% for demonstration
\begin{document}
\begin{marginfigure}
  \tikz\fill[cyan] rectangle(\marginparwidth,2);
  \caption{Some caption for the blue figure.}
\end{marginfigure}
\begin{figure}
  \tikz\fill[yellow]rectangle(\textwidth,4);
  \caption[][3cm]{Some caption for the yellow figure.}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure*}
  \tikz\fill[magenta]rectangle(\textwidth,3);
  \setfloatalignment{b} %force caption above
  \caption{Some caption for the magenta figure.}
\end{figure*}
\begin{figure*}
  \tikz\fill[green!30]rectangle(\textwidth,3);
  \caption[][-1.2em]{Some caption for the green figure.}
\end{figure*}
\begin{figure*}[b]
  \tikz\fill[gray!30]rectangle(\textwidth,3);
  \caption{Some caption for the gray figure.}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the intention of the `zzzname` macros is that they should _only_ have text (to be easily translated) so `\renewcommand{\figurename}{\textbf{Figure}}` is not really following the guidelines, the styling of the name should be elsewhere, `\figurename` should just be the text Figure in the current language.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've made some progress and updated the code in a way that do not change `\figurename`.  My problem is not really related to `\figurename` but to the way the figure environment of tufte captures the caption and displays it afterwards, ignoring any (re)definition local to the environment.

Comment: Since figure* could be either above or below the caption, you need the actual relative positions. You could use \tikzmark, or create you own aux file system using \pdfsavepos, \pdflastypos and \pdflastxpos

Comment: @JohnKormylo With the tufte style, I usually have to shift the captions explicitly so they look nice, so I know beforehand if it is above or below and I'm ok with replacing \caption{...} by \captionabove{...} or \captiondown{...} as appropriate.  But I agree getting this figured automatically would be nice.  The tufte code seems to use `\floatalignment` to decide if the caption is above or below, so maybe I can simply check this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good workaround for what is happening is to define a command which resets the label of a figure. Afterwards, employ `\AfterEndEnvironment` (from `etoolbox`) to execute such command after every `figure` and `figure*` environment. This way, you might be able to redefine how caption should look like but also still get the original definition of figures caption after the environment ends.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,nobib]{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
    \renewcommand{\fnum@figure}{\textbf{\figurename}~\thefigure}
    % save older version of \fnum@figure
    \let \fnum@figureold \fnum@figure
    % define a command to reset to the older version
    \newcommand{\resetfnumfigure}{\let \fnum@figure \fnum@figureold}
\makeatother

\AfterEndEnvironment{figure}{\resetfnumfigure}
\AfterEndEnvironment{figure*}{\resetfnumfigure}


\makeatletter
    \newcommand{\captionsbelow}{%
      \renewcommand{\fnum@figure}{$\blacktriangle$~\textbf{\figurename}~\thefigure}}
    \newcommand{\captionsright}{%
      \renewcommand{\fnum@figure}{$\blacktriangleleft$~\textbf{\figurename}~\thefigure}}
    \newcommand{\captionsabove}{%
      \renewcommand{\fnum@figure}{$\blacktriangledown$~\textbf{\figurename}~\thefigure}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{marginfigure}
    \captionsbelow
  \tikz\fill[cyan] rectangle(\marginparwidth,2);
  \caption{Some caption for the blue figure.}
\end{marginfigure}
\captionsright
\begin{figure}
  \tikz\fill[yellow]rectangle(\textwidth,4);
  \caption[][3cm]{Some caption for the yellow figure.}
\end{figure}
\captionsabove
\begin{figure*}
  \tikz\fill[magenta]rectangle(\textwidth,3);
  \caption[][-4.5cm]{Some caption for the magenta figure.}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks!  `AfterEndEnvironment` and `AtEndEnvironment` was exactly the last bit I needed to hook into floating code for the tufte class.  I've updated the question with the revised code I'm now using, and I'm going to accept this answer.

Comment: @JohnKormylo it would revert if it was changed in the environment.  The situation is that in the tufte class, the caption for `figure` and `figure*` are not typeset inside those environments: they are saved, and then typeset in the `\end` par of the environment. So changing `\fnum@figure` in the environment would have no effect on the caption.  That's why calling the `\captionsabove` or `\captionsright` macros were still done outside of the environment in this example.